# sitefinity customized widget didn't display any content when updated into development server

Tags: sitefinity

I have designed a customized widget to display all the subscribers in backend page, It works perfectly fine locally , but when stage into server (client server) ,initially , it works as expected ,but suddenly the widget is not working and display nothing after period of time, the only exception is the log is Telerik.OpenAccess.Exceptions.NoSuchObjectException occurred and was caught, I searched and it shows it's a bug in sitefinity that exists in the old version . my version is far more updated to have such a bug. any possible answer?

Comment: can't help without first seeing some of the relevant code

Comment: Is your staging server stable and upgraded correctly?  Often I see that older DLLs, that are no longer needed, are left on a server, and interfere.  Sometimes it is just another developer with an older version of Sitefinity deploys files again that were already deleted.

Do a full compare between the environment that works and the environment that doesn't, you'll probably see the issue.  It sounds like bad DevOps not bad code.

This is all guessing and @VeselinVasilev is right, the community can't help without seeing the code.